# What is a good synonym for "devil"?

Tags: synonyms

If a person is very evil some would say he is a *devil*.

Can anyone give me another word—*devil* sounds a bit strange to me.

Comment: There is no *good* synonym for devil. Devils are bad, remember?

Comment: @Robusto: But surely, even devils have mommies who love them very much?

Comment: Hmm, fictional evil person... Skeletor?

Comment: @Orbling Fictional characters are not interchangeable, not to mention that calling the devil 'fictional' is somewhat incendiary.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing the context, it's hard to answer this.

Menace, villain, fiend, cad.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I'm partial to the term "hellion", but "troublemaker", "nogoodnik", "problem child", "rabble-rouser", "incendiary", and many other words already given are all good words.

Comment: By most people's lights, Hitler was a truly evil man, and they might thus have said he was a/the devil. Good as they are in other contexts, I don't think your words would be applied to Hitler.

Comment: If you've ever seen a video of Hitler giving a speech, I think you would have no trouble calling him an incendiary rabble-rouser.

Comment: Ah, you got me with the most defendable one in the list! But in the broader historical context rabble-rousing isn't really what the man is usually remembered for, and it's not particularly indicative of what we mean when we say he was *evil*.

Comment: These words better describe Loki than Lucifer.

Comment: @PhilN. Very true.

Answer (score 3):

Without more context, I quite like **brute** or **beast**; you can also go with 
*monster*, *varmint*, *fiend*, etc.

If you want to convey the meaning of mischievous, yet somewhat likeable, you could go with
**rascal**, *rogue*, *imp*, or *scamp*.

Comment: +1 for monster, I think that is the best suggestion that people might use in normal speech.

Answer (score 3):

6 answers already and no one has suggested: Demon, Satan, Lucifer or even simply: "fallen".

Comment: ...Oops... typo

Answer (score 2):

http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/evil/

> Sense 1: evil (vs. good):
> atrocious,
> flagitious, grievous,
> monstrous, bad, black, dark,
> sinister, corruptive, perversive,
> pestiferous, demonic, diabolic,
> diabolical, fiendish, hellish,
> infernal, satanic, unholy, despicable,
> ugly, vile, slimy, unworthy,
> worthless, wretched, devilish, diabolic,
> diabolical, mephistophelian,
> mephistophelean, evil-minded
>
> Also See:
> bad; immoral; offensive;
> unrighteous; wicked; wrong
>
> Sense 2: evil, vicious, wicked (vs.
> virtuous)
>
> Sense 3: malefic,
> malevolent, malign, evil, maleficent
> (vs. beneficent)

Comment: Nice reference, but it's missing some commas.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at what others have recommended, *rapscallion* may be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

All the words I thought of were already mentioned with the exception of:

- Knave
- Miscreant
- Scoundrel

Answer (score 0):

Let's not forget the ever popular "bounder".

"Evil incarnate" may work if you're looking for something particularly strong.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not really synonymous with *devil,* a contemporary word which implies the immorality and depraved nature of an evil person is *reprobate.*

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Christi's *evil incarnate*, most existing answers imply people more "naughty" than truly "evil". And in this increasingly secular age, words like *Demon, Satan, Lucifer* are a bit odd.

Ongoing [secularisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularization), [liberalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberalism), advances in [psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology), etc., mean the defining characteristic *evil* that OP wants included is becoming harder to pin down. But I suggest the best word is...

> [psychopath](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/psychopath) - a person with a personality disorder characterized by a tendency to commit antisocial and sometimes violent acts and a failure to feel guilt for such acts.

Comment: I understood that a psychopath is, precisely, *amoral*, where evil is *immoral*.  And if you talk to people who have encountered both (senior policemen, in my case), I think they will say that 'evil people' are quite different from 'those unrestrained by guilt'.

Comment: @TimLymington: As implied by my second paragraph, it's difficult to identify *any* examples of "evil" that meet everyone's definition of a word which some would argue has no real-world referent anyway. I'm not a psychologist, but I don't believe psychopathy is a precisely-defined "disease" which *always* includes the symptom "never feels guilt". Nor do I think the more general [antisocial personality disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisocial_personality_disorder) excludes such people, or includes special subcategories for those who do feel guilt.