# What's a formal-noun that means an unprincipled, unpleasant person?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I am trying to find a word that can be used in **formal**  situations for referring to an unprincipled, unpleasant person. I'm looking for a more formal or civil way to say this, rather than the uncivil “He’s a jerk/bastard.”.

There is an old word, “scoundrel” which is no longer used but which is close to the word I’m looking for.

Does anyone know of such a word?

Comment: Scoundrel isn't particularly common these days but I wouldn't say it was no longer used. So you're after a word in common modern usage?

Comment: There is a question on a word for [a very evil person](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17996/what-is-a-good-synonym-for-devil/), which maybe isn't the same thing? Also one on the [modern equivalent of scoundrel](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/405832/what-is-the-modern-equivalent-of-scoundrel) but the answers are mostly informal. But I'd say using those and a thesaurus you should get something.

Comment: Hello. Bob. Please show research, as expected in questions on ELU. Using a thesaurus to find synonyms (some of which may be formal in register) is a good place to start; even "the 7 synonyms listed by 'Allthesaurus" have no formal examples", with a link, would be fine.

Comment: In what formal situation are you thinking of using an ad hominem? Assuming your question isn't answered in either the linked questions or a thesaurus, please [edit] in more information about the context, including a sample sentence. See the [tag wiki](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for more details.

Comment: A [meta-question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15583) has been raised about the justifiability of closing this question as opinion-based.

Comment: *unprincipled* and *unpleasant* are two different concepts, and I don’t think there’s a two-for-one word for them.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 2):

Who says *scoundrel* is old-fashioned? [According to Ngram Viewer,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=scoundrel&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) it's become *more* common over the past few decades. I see no reason to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the person is "uncivil", which is very formal. It means "discourteous; impolite".

In general, we would say that a jerk/bastard lacks basic civility.

Comment: While these are adjectives, they are more like \how people say jerk without saying it.

Answer (score 1):

How about "blackguard"?
[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/blackguard) defines it as:

> 1. a low, contemptible person; scoundrel.

Also "[rascal](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rascal)" is defined as:

> 1. a base, dishonest, or unscrupulous person.
> 2. a mischievous person or animal:
>    *That child is a real rascal.*

Comment: Well, yeah, *blackguard* and *rascal* are far more current than *scoundrel* :-))

Answer (score 1):

According to Collins dictionary a [**reprobate**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reprobate) is

> an unprincipled or totally bad person

also

> a depraved, unprincipled, or wicked person

Merriam-Webster also defines a reprobate as

> an unprincipled or depraved person: SCOUNDREL, ROGUE